# Emoji Keyboard Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, emoji

I would like help / need support getting an emoji keyboard in linux ubuntu 20.04 lts latest version, You know like in Apple iPhones and Android smartphones when you have your on screen keyboard and there's an emoji icon to select emoji well I want that with my on screen keyboard in ubuntu. Is there a way, I think it's possible and has been done so any Tips / help . I value any comments and support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Ubuntu focal, you could try this in the ubuntu terminal:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

if it's not updated you could try going into ubuntu software > Updates tab and update through there.

if it still doesn't get updated, then I do know that Ubuntu Jammy jellyfish(22.04) has an updated version of the emoji keyboard. to upgrade, go to the terminal and type this command:

`sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Comment: Thank You , I will try that. Yeah I'm pretty sure on another PC (maybe upgraded) it was there so yeah Thanks. I will try an upgrade soon Thanks.

Comment: your welcome. they had released a new version for the emoji keyboard(jammy jellyfish) some few minutes after I posted this answer.

Comment: Wow , Thanks again man this really helped! I upgraded yesterday and working fine, it was frustrating that I had to upgrade to ubuntu 21.10 and that took about 4/5 hours and the next day to ubuntu 22.04 lts haha which took around the same time but it was worth it, you've helped me out with this one Thanks, Have a good day or night where you are.

Comment: you are welcome:) please accept my answer so people know it's already answered.